# Android Java sharedPreferences logic issue

Tags: java, android

**Android Java `sharedPreferences` logic issue**

I have an app that has a sign in and sign out in it.

I want, when the user first downloads the app, it is sign out. Then when he signs in using the button, a `sharedPreference` value saves. Now next time he opens the app, it will automatically sign him in. Lets say he signs out then closes the app, so now when he opens it, it will sign him out. Thats how it goes like most apps.

What I did, at the first of the activity I added this

```
    SharedPreferences SiggnedIn = getSharedPreferences("YesOrNo", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = SiggnedIn.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("SiggnedIn?", false);
    editor.commit();
```

then when the user clicks the button to signs out

```
                            SharedPreferences SiggnedIn = getSharedPreferences("YesOrNo", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = SiggnedIn.edit();
                            editor.putBoolean("SiggnedIn?", false);
                            editor.commit();
```

and if he clicks it to sign in

```
                                 SharedPreferences SiggnedIn = getSharedPreferences("YesOrNo", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
                                 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = SiggnedIn.edit();
                                 editor.putBoolean("SiggnedIn?", true);
                                 editor.commit();
```

and at last, if I have a method that updates everything every second.

so in it, I add

```
            SharedPreferences SiggnedIn = getSharedPreferences("YesOrNo", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
            boolean myIntValue = SiggnedIn.getBoolean("SiggnedIn?", false);

            if(myIntValue){
                SignHimIn();
            }
```

That doesn't work.

Comment: `YesOrNo` and `SiggnedIn?` aren't really good keys (may just be my opinion). Take a look at this question and look at the answer to see if that might help you out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep things simple

**Check Status**

```
SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("userSession", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
boolean isLoggedIn = pref.getBoolean("isLoggedIn", false);
```

**Sign In**

```
SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("userSession", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
editor.putBoolean("isLoggedIn", true);
editor.commit();
```

**Sign Out**

```
SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("userSession", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
editor.putBoolean("isLoggedIn", false);
editor.commit();
```

---

**Simple Logic**

```
protected boolean isUserSignedIn(){
    boolean isLoggedIn = false;

    SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("userSession", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    isLoggedIn = pref.getBoolean("isLoggedIn", false);//false is just default

    return isLoggedIn;
}
```

**Usage**

```
if(!isUserSignedIn()){
   SignHimIn();
}
```

Comment: Hi, good answer but in "Check Status" and "Simple Logic",  `editor.commit();` has no sense.

Comment: You also do not need to define `isLoggedIn ` twice.

Comment: Thanks guys, these were copy past typos

Answer (score 2):

**This is not supposed to work, because each time the app is launched, you are overwriting `SiggnedIn?` to false.**

```
SharedPreferences SiggnedIn = getSharedPreferences("YesOrNo", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = SiggnedIn.edit();
editor.putBoolean("SiggnedIn?", false);
editor.commit();
```

I would suggest using another key for `SharedPreferences` to identify if the app is launched for the first time.

```
SharedPreferences SiggnedIn = getSharedPreferences("YesOrNo", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);

if (SiggnedIn.getBoolean("APP_LAUNCHED_FIRST_TIME", true)) {
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = SiggnedIn.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("APP_LAUNCHED_FIRST_TIME", false);
    editor.commit();

    //For the first time, user should be signed out
    editor.putBoolean("SiggnedIn?", false);
    editor.commit();
}
```

Then in the `Activity` launch, check if user is signed in or not.

```
if (SiggnedIn.getBoolean("SiggnedIn?", false)) {
    SignHimIn();
}
```

Rest `Sign in` and `Sign out` logic is Ok. I assume that you are doing this in `Button` click.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you setting the boolean to false when you first launch your activity? You should just rely on the default value of getBoolean (which you defined as false) - This means that if you didn't put anything yet in the SignedIn field it will still return false.

Solution:

Inside your login button

```
SharedPreferences mPrefs= getSharedPreferences("mPrefsName", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
editor.putBoolean("isSignedIn",true);
editor.commit();
```

When your activity starts (notice the false next to isSignedIn - this is the default value)

```
SharedPreferences mPrefs= getSharedPreferences("mPrefsName", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
if(mPrefs.getBoolean("isSignedIn",false))
DoStuff();
```

And inside logout button (NOT on activity start)

```
SharedPreferences mPrefs= getSharedPreferences("mPrefsName", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
editor.putBoolean("isSignedIn",false);
editor.commit();
```